# SVN repository seemingly stopped increasing its size

Tags: svn

This is not exactly a problem that needs solving, but rather a technical question out of sheer curiosity.

I have this ancient, 12 years old SVN repository with over 45,000 revisions within it. It's huge, with terabytes and possibly a million files within it, some of them alone with well over 2 GB.

The thing is, I noticed it seemingly no longer increasing significantly, even though I continue to use it and add more and more files to it. I had to exchange the disk on the server due to age, but the 4 TB disk fits with considerable room.

I don't know how the SVN filesystem works internally (I suspect there are a lot of hardlinks in there), and thus I just wonder:

Is it the expected behavior for such SVN repo?

Comment: I suppose the short answer will be "yes". With longer explanation "Deltas for change for any file is smaller, than the whole file and for old long history you have now only deltas for all effected by earlier commits files"